# How logic master volume control by Applescript?

Tags: applescript, logic

I Create one application via Applescript, and desktop to run this application,

I will automatically open the project file for a particular logic. After moving to the first track, but is the syntax to play.

I've created so far. Problem, but next to it.

When i make another application program via the Applescript,

It is got to try to fade out the Master Volume of the currently running logic, 
but I tries to fade out,I do not know way.

How logic master volume control by Applescript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't believe Logic has support for AppleScript.  Its a shame too, there are many cool things that a scripting engine would open up.